# Android Tablet IDE for Python and Java

Tags: android, ide, arm, tablet

Are there any ARM-based programming environments (IDE) for Android tablets which are not emulated? (preferably Python or Java)

Tablets are becoming a more popular utensil in schools and a stable environment will be useful in a Computer Science program.

Comment: Its not been done but I would say that nothing is impossible. Take a look at Maxine (https://wikis.oracle.com/display/MaxineVM/Home) it is a fully function JDK written entirely in java. If that could be ported to android in theory you could make something work. But it would take a lot of work.

Comment: Also check out http://www.idedroid.com/  I believe it basically lets you write the code in android then sends the text file to a server which compiles and runs it and sends you back the results. If not someone should do that XD

Comment: Oh my, it's hard enough to connect to wifi as it is when competing with thousands of other students. xD

Comment: I really don't see the use of an IDE for an tablet, given that most tablets don't have an physical keyboard. Imagine the problems of typing millions of code lines into an device that uses an touch given keyboard, it's like using the mouse to program.
In short, an human has 10 fingers that it can use to type, so why should one want to be limited to only one?

Comment: If you were to code on a tablet you would do so with a keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not specifically ARM, but here is an IDE for Android tablets that can compile Java/Android apps: [Terminal IDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside).

Answer (score 5):

As of now there are only a few good tools available. One is [AIDE](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aide.ui). It has a great editor with code completion, on-the-fly error checking and supports the full edit-compile-run cycle for Android Apps.

It works fine on my devices (Transformer Prime and Samsung Galaxy S2).

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but AIDE doesn't seem to be able to debug code (e.g. setting breakpoints, stepping, inspection, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use DroidDevelop. This is written special for tablets.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop

http://en.assoft.ru/droiddevelop

Answer (score 0):

easyGUI is a little IDE for Android XML Files. You can design your Layout Files on the phone or tablet. Also good for teaching.

[easyGUI Android XML IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.easyGUI)